# My location blue dot is not being in center of the screen when changing camera to my location

Tags: swift, google-maps

[image]

I am facing an issue with blue dot that shows the user's location, the issue is 
when pressing go to my location button, the blue dot is not centered in the map but it's below a bit.

```
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
       location = locations.last!
       let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: (location.coordinate.latitude), longitude: (location.coordinate.longitude), zoom: 17.0)
       if isBeggining {
          self.mapView.camera = camera
       } else {
          self.mapView.animate(to: camera)
       }
       isBeggining = false
       self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
```

Comment: Can I see code you put inside the My Location button Action.

Comment: @HarshadPipaliya updated in the question

Comment: didTapMyLocationButtonForMapView can I se this function code?